# I can't ssh to Raspberry Pi, even if I created empty ssh file

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi

I have a new Raspberry Pi Zero WH, and I can't ssh to it no matter how I try

I have done following steps

1. Using `rpi-imager` I have etched "Debian Bullseye with Desktop" to a brand new SD card
2. Using `ctrl`+`shift`+`x` I have selected enable SSH, locale details, and Wi-Fi details
3. After the `/boot` volume is created, I have added empty file named `ssh` to `/media/myUserName/boot` and a `wpa_supplicant.conf` with correct data
4. Ejected the SD card and implanted it in Raspberry Pi
5. Connected Raspberry Pi to power. Wait until LED is no longer flashing (and then 20 mins, just in case).
6. Using router client, I found the IP address of the Raspberry Pi (let's say `192.168.0.154`). I set it as reserved IP. I notice that the device is listed as `unknown` and not as `raspberrypi`, not sure if this is relevant
7. Using `ping 192.168.0.154` I verified that PI is there

Now `ssh pi@192.168.0.154` should connect to the Pi, but all I get is
`ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.115 port 22: Connection refused`

I have successfully used this computer to `ssh` outside of my local network before. I haven't changed any settings (that I know of) since. I have tried from a different computer (running Windows), same error.

All answers I could find recommended step 3, but that didn't help me. What are my options now?

Comment: Except the `unknown` device name, everything sounds good to me. Are you sure you are connecting to the good device ? Could it be that the Pi is not connected to your network ?

Comment: Oh shoot! It was my phone :D Now to figure out how to connect Pi to my network (since wpa_supplicant.conf didn't work, apparently)

Comment: I would advise you using a RJ45 network cable for the first connection, do you have this somewhere ?

Comment: As my comment was the answer to your question, I published it as an answer that you can validate :)

Comment: I do have the ethernet cable, but this Pi doesn't have hardware input for it

Also, finding Ethernet to Micro USB adapter is almost impossible in 2022. So I have bought Ethernet to USB-A, and female USB-A to Micro USB.

This is how adapter hell starts :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device you're trying to connect is mostlikely not the raspberry pi as the step your describe seems good but the device is named `unknown`. If you don't see it on your router, it probably didn't connect to the Wifi.

For the first connection I would advise using a wired connection, so you are sure that the network connection is established and stable.